# JTable Is not Adding Vector on Click Event of Label

Tags: java, swing, events, vector, jtable

I have a JTable And I have set Vector into the Header and Vector of Vector as Row content but it has to be add header onclick event. but when i tried to add String into the vector in click event its adding String into the Vector but that vector is not added to the Header so how can i make that i have Used firetablechanged event of model. but its not working some how.

here sample code.

```
Vector vector;
Vector<Vector> vector_content;
table = new javax.swing.JTable();

table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(vector_content,vector){

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

now i have click event like this where m adding data into the Header table of content.

```
            vector = new Vector();
            vector_content = new Vector<Vector>();
            vector.add("Employee Name");
            vector.add("Date");
            vector.add("Type");
```

data is added to the Vector i can print data but some how its not set to the table how can i make it?

example
here its working because i have added Table model using that col vector and row but when i use that in some button click then its not working method name is **![setDate();][1]**

```
public class Jtable_Column extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Vector col;
    public Vector<Vector> row;

    /**
     * Creates new form Jtable_Column
     */
    public Jtable_Column() {

        setData();
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(row,col
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 1, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jtable_Column.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jtable_Column.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jtable_Column.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jtable_Column.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Jtable_Column().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration

    private void setData() {
        col = new Vector();
        row = new Vector<Vector>();
        col.add("first");
        col.add("Sec");
        col.add("third");
        col.add("third");
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Are you adding a new row or new columns?

Comment: @AndrewThompson i have added Simple code that what is there and have told what i want to achieve and i have provide some sample code of table model table and even vector that how i am doing. what more u want?

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank god u came and ya i am adding that in to the table header means that Vector is first null i mean no data and when i click that at that time data is added to vector and i want to show that vector as header of table.

Comment: @MadProgrammer when i am calling same thing in to the Constructor its working but when put on click its not working :(

Comment: Seems like you are creating new vectors with new data but you do not pass these new vectors to the table data model.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin i have already set that data into the Headers :)

Comment: *"what more u want?"*  I don't want anything.  `JTable` works just fine for me.  If ***you*** want help, I suggest you read the linked document.  2 uncompilable code snippets does not make for an MCVE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson leave it dude i got my answer. at least somebody getting what i am posting that is enough see madprogrammer's ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) has a number of helpful methods, one of which is `addColumn`...

```
TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.addColumn("Employee Name");
model.addColumn("Date");
model.addColumn("Type");
```

If you want to remove the existing columns, you can use `setColumnCount` and pass it `0` first

**Updated based on additional example**

Basically, I did this and it worked fine...

```
jTable1.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setColumnCount(0);
        model.addColumn("Banans");
        model.addColumn("Apples");
        model.addColumn("Pears");
        model.addColumn("Fluffy");
        model.addColumn("Unicorns");
    }

});
```

You should never modify the state of any data that the model might be relying from out side the model, as doing so could potentially place the UI into an unstable state

Comment: I'm assuming you've not added the "extra" question yet ;)

Comment: haha no ofc not i have trust that u will give ans with out that ;)

Comment: and ya btw if i have set Vector as header would it add that String object in that Vector too???

Comment: Based on your code example, no.  You've created a new instance of the `Vector`, which means that the what the `TableModel` has and what you are manipulating is not the same, and even if they were the same, you shouldn't do it, as the header and table won't be update

Comment: But when i add that Vector inthe Header of TableModel and when i call it in Constructor then its setting data but out of Constructor its not Working. and other thing is that. if i have set that as Header of Table then if i add that Header in table why not that vector not updating?

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` maintains it's own internal cache, stopping you from corrupting it.  As to the first part, I'd need to see working code before I could comment

Comment: okey wait i will show you okey i am making similler example it will take 5 min okey bro :)

Comment: I have added sample code of that. Check it out that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jTable1.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setColumnCount(0);
        model.addColumn("Banans");
        model.addColumn("Apples");
        model.addColumn("Pears");
        model.addColumn("Fluffy");
        model.addColumn("Unicorns");
        model.reload();
    }

});
```